# How to resolve SSL Certificate Error while installing PIP?

Tags: centos, python, ssl, pip

When I'm trying to install PIP using the downloaded package from bootstrap.pypa.io, I'm getting SSL Certificate error. I've followed other posts and tried doing this by disabling the certificate check in `/etc/python/cert-verification.cfg` and tried using `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0` but this doesn't seem to work and finally I have decided to ask this questions because other posts don't really help my case.

**I have the following Environment:**

```
OS: centos-release-7-5.1804.1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

**Python Packages:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum list installed|grep python
dbus-python.x86_64                    1.1.1-9.el7                    @anaconda
libselinux-python.x86_64              2.5-12.el7                     @anaconda
newt-python.x86_64                    0.52.15-4.el7                  @anaconda
python.x86_64                         2.7.5-69.el7_5                 @updates
python-backports.x86_64               1.0-8.el7                      @base
python-backports-ssl_match_hostname.noarch
python-configobj.noarch               4.7.2-7.el7                    @anaconda
python-decorator.noarch               3.4.0-3.el7                    @anaconda
python-firewall.noarch                0.4.4.4-14.el7                 @anaconda
python-gobject-base.x86_64            3.22.0-1.el7_4.1               @anaconda
python-iniparse.noarch                0.4-9.el7                      @anaconda
python-ipaddress.noarch               1.0.16-2.el7                   @base
python-libs.x86_64                    2.7.5-69.el7_5                 @updates
python-linux-procfs.noarch            0.4.9-3.el7                    @anaconda
python-perf.x86_64                    3.10.0-862.9.1.el7             @updates
python-pycurl.x86_64                  7.19.0-19.el7                  @anaconda
python-pyudev.noarch                  0.15-9.el7                     @anaconda
python-schedutils.x86_64              0.4-6.el7                      @anaconda
python-setuptools.noarch              0.9.8-7.el7                    @base
python-slip.noarch                    0.4.0-4.el7                    @anaconda
python-slip-dbus.noarch               0.4.0-4.el7                    @anaconda
python-urlgrabber.noarch              3.10-8.el7                     @anaconda
python-wheel.noarch                   0.24.0-2.el7                   @epel
rpm-python.x86_64                     4.11.3-32.el7                  @anaconda
```

**Following are the steps and Errors:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1604k  100 1604k    0     0  73257      0  0:00:22  0:00:22 --:--:-- 72502
[root@localhost ~]#

[root@localhost ~]# PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),))
```

I would like to add, Python was pre-installed with the OS and I'm trying to install PIP directly. I tried installed from epel-repo but I get a older version and when I try to update it (because without update, I keep getting error for installing the new version of PIP) I get the same error.

Could anyone suggest how to get this fixed?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I have installed CentOS in my personal machine on VM.
openssl is also installed.
# yum list installed|grep openssl
openssl.x86_64                        1:1.0.2k-12.el7                [@]anaconda
openssl-libs.x86_64                   1:1.0.2k-12.el7               [@]anaconda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something about your situation that doesn't add up. I just did the exact commands as you in a CentOS 7.5 VM and they worked without issue:

*os version*

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

*download*

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1604k  100 1604k    0     0  1676k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1676k
```

*install*

```
$ PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 7.4MB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 4.4MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0 wheel-0.31.1
```

#### Workaround

To workaround this issue you can amend the following file on Linux/Unix to tell `pip` to just trust this host:

```
$ cat ~/.pip/pip.conf
[global]
trusted-host = files.pythonhosted.org
               bootstrap.pypa.io
```

Or just do it as a one-off:
bootstrap.pypa.io

*Why would I need this?*

It's likely that either the country you're in or a corporate firewall is inserting itself as a trusted host, and is messing with the actual host where the data is coming from. This typically wreaks havoc on SSL certificates since they include the host/domainname that they're explicitly created for.

#### Debugging tip

When you run into issues such as this with Python you can always enable verbose logging via the `-vvv` switches:

```
$ PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 python -vvv get-pip.py |& less
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# trying /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.so
# trying /usr/lib64/python2.7/sitemodule.so
# trying /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.pyc
# trying /usr/lib64/python2.7/os.so
# trying /usr/lib64/python2.7/osmodule.so
...
import pip._vendor.html5lib._ihatexml # loaded from Zip /tmp/tmpYDym4g/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_ihatexml.py
import pip._vendor.html5lib.treebuilders.etree # loaded from Zip /tmp/tmpYDym4g/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/html5lib/treebuilders/etree.py
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.0
...
```

By doing this you can see the URLs that the `get-pip.py` script is getting tripped up on.

#### References

- [pip install fails with “connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: @AnkitVashistha - yeah unfortunately w/o the exact issue on my end to replicate, I cannot say beyond what I said above as to why + how to work around it. The cmd I gave you was meant to look through the hostnames coming across and verify if there are any names not explicitly covered by the cert. It's not a easy thing to debug unfortunately.

Comment: @slm: I noticed that even after this, post installing Dokcer-CE when i run the docker test, it was giving me errors related to certificates.
# docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid.
See 'docker run --help'.
When i started looking how to resolve this, i came across another post where a user had suggested to check the System time if that was correct. Post installing ntp package and syncing with time.google.com, i am not getting errors

Comment: @AnkitVashistha - interesting, so it was the date/time on the system? I've never run into that.